# Script that highlights entire row after finding duplicate cells in column google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to figure out how to make a button through script in google sheets thats going to be pressed on the cell that’s currently active, go through the entire column of cells to find a duplicate of the previous active cell, and then highlight the row that each duplicate cell is on. Any ideas?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script and the detail of your goal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getDataRange().setBackground("#ffffff");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const v = sh.getActiveRange().getValue();

  let lo = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastone');
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastone', v);
  if (lo) {
    let tf = sh.createTextFinder(lo).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
    tf.forEach(f => {
      sh.getRange(f.getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#ffff00");
    });
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty()` to bypass the time limit?

Comment: @YuriKhristich I suppose there is a point but I don't know what it is.