# onSelectionChange re-triggers itself when changing tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've been trying to get a simple function to work for a couple of days but I can't see where I'm going wrong. I would really appreciate some help is possible please.

**Background**:
I have a calendar tab with a table containing Stores down the side and Dates across the top.

When the user clicks between E7:AI200 I want to be able to:

- Grab the Store Name from column 1 and the clicked row and populate B1 with the value.
- Grab the Date from row 1 and the clicked column and populate C1 with the value.

*This seems to work fine.*

I also want the spreadsheet to automatically navigate to another tab called 'Filtered Events' when the cell between E7:AI200 clicked.

*This also seems to work fine.*

**Issue**: When I click back to the Calendar tab it seems to re-click the original cell and navigates me straight back to the 'Filtered Events' tab and I am stuck in a loop of continously going between tabs each time I try to get back to the Calendar.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Calendar") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    
    var full_range = sheet.getRange("A1:AI200");
    var click_range = e.range;

    var row_lookup = click_range.getRow();
    var col_lookup = click_range.getColumn();

    var selected_store = full_range.getCell(row_lookup, 1).getValue();
    var selected_date = full_range.getCell(1, col_lookup).getValue();

    var populate_store = sheet.getRange("B1"); 
    var populate_date = sheet.getRange("C1");

    if (row_lookup > 6 && row_lookup < 250 && col_lookup < 36 && col_lookup > 4) { 

      populate_store.setValue(selected_store);
      populate_date.setValue(selected_date);

      var change_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filtered Events");
      change_sheet.activate();
    } 

    else {
      populate_store.setValue('');
      populate_date.setValue('');
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, as a workaround, you can chose some 'safe' cell (A1, for example) on the 'Calendar' sheet and activate the cell at some moment after one of these clicks. At the start of the script you can check, if the active cell is 'A1' and do nothing in this case.

Comment: Another approach: you can use `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty()` to save the coordinates of the last clicked cell and check it with `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty()` at the start of the script. If the coordinates are the same, do nothing. Example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70374018/14265469

Comment: Thank you - are you able to help with how that would look in my script please? I'm having difficulty knowing how to implement it

Comment: I just added the example how the `PropertiesService` can be used.

Comment: Why not just use a checkbox and a onEdit trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store the last used coordinates of selected cell and check them at the start of the script:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Calendar") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");
    
    var full_range = sheet.getRange("A1:AI200");
    var click_range = e.range;

    var row_lookup = click_range.getRow();
    var col_lookup = click_range.getColumn();

    // try to get the last used cell coordinates
    var last_cell_row = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last_cell_row');
    var last_cell_col = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last_cell_col');

    // save current cell coordinates
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last_cell_row', row_lookup);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last_cell_col', col_lookup);

    // if the coordinates are the same break the function
    if (row_lookup == last_cell_row && col_lookup == last_cell_col) return;

    // the rest of your code ...
```

I haven't tested it. It would be better if you provide some dummy data for testing, how your sheets look like.